# Accesse external USB camera using camera2 API or other

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2

I am trying to develop an app to capture image from an external USB camera.

When i list down the camera devices using cameraManager it only shows the internal cameras (Front and Back).

When i do,

```html
packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_EXTERNAL)
```

it returns false which means external camera support is not available in my android tablet.

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Android version?